# How to convert EST time zone to PST, IST, HST in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, timezone-offset

As the daylight time zone changes so how would I get the correct time zone offset to get the time zone converted.

Ex time difference between EST and IST is 9:30hrs but in daylight time zone(DST) it becomes 10:30 hrs.

So how would I get the correct updated timezone offset

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of different ways to achieve this, and you can use the AT TIME ZONE function to convert datetime values.
The below example uses a CTE (CTEDateTimes) as the input for a list of UTC datetime (UTDDateTime) values for the datetimes between midnight and 04:00 22-03-13.

The following statement will return both the UTC datetime and the converted Eastern Standard Time (US).

```
SELECT
UTDDateTime
,CONVERT(DATETIME2(0), UTDDateTime, 126) AT TIME ZONE 'Eastern Standard Time' EST
FROM CTEDateTimes
```

The output for around 02:00 hours UTC are as follows:

```
UTCDateTime             <---> EST
----------------------- ----- ---------------------------
2022-03-13 01:57:00.000 <---> 2022-03-13 01:57:00 -05:00 
2022-03-13 01:58:00.000 <---> 2022-03-13 01:58:00 -05:00
2022-03-13 01:59:00.000 <---> 2022-03-13 01:59:00 -05:00
2022-03-13 02:00:00.000 <---> 2022-03-13 03:00:00 -04:00
2022-03-13 02:01:00.000 <---> 2022-03-13 03:01:00 -04:00
2022-03-13 02:02:00.000 <---> 2022-03-13 03:02:00 -04:00
```

In this way you can convert to any time zone and then find the offset.

Hope this assists.